# why JS for loop doesn't work if i put return keyword?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, return

when i put the **return** keyword like this example:

```
for (let z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
   return console.log('one');
  }
//the result is : 'one'
```

but when i remove the **return** keyword like this example:

```
for (let z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
   console.log('one');
  }
//the result is : 'one', 'one', 'one', 'one', 'one'
```

the loop works and return ***five 'one'***
what's the reason for that ?

Comment: Because `return` breaks out of the loop after the first iteration same way if you've put `break;` in there.

Comment: [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) exits the function scope entirely, and returns the value to the caller.  I'm not sure what you are attempting to accomplish by using it in the above example, because `console.log('one')` doesn't itself return any value, so you'd be returning `undefined`.

Comment: Also: _"the loop works and return five 'one' what's the reason for that ?"_ - please note that _`return`ing_ is different from _logging_.  Your function logs to the console 'one' five times-- but it never returns anything.

Answer (score 1):

`return` returns the value, ending the function immediately.

It doesn't start the next iteration of the loop because that is part of the function (which you've returned from).

Answer (score 1):

The loop is a statement, it says "do {thing} for some number of times based on a condition". But if you `return`, you are telling the loop to stop, to immediately exit and give you whatever you are returning.

In this case, `console.log` doesn't *do* anything directly, it just prints to the console as a side effect. It isn't *returning* anything.

It doesn't resolve to a value, so what you're doing in the first example is actually returning `undefined` after one iteration of the loop (and console.log still prints that one value to the console, as you've noticed).